# C++ Global and Scoped integers initial values

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, global-variables, initialization

A Four bytes memory slot is reserved for every defined integer. Uninitialised variable maintains the old value of that slot. hence, the initial value is somehow randomised.

```
int x = 5; // definition with initialisation
```

This fact in most C++ compilers as far as I know holds for scoped variables. But, when it comes to global variables. a value of zero will be set.

```
int x; // uninitialised definition
```

Why does the C++ Compiler behave differently regarding to the initial value of the global and scoped variables.

Is it fundamental?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace level variables (which means global) belong to **static** storage duration, and as per the Standard, all variables with static storage duration are statically initialized, which means all bits are set 0:

§3.6.2/2 from the C++ Standard (n3242) says,

> **Variables with static storage duration** (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) **shall be zero-initialized** (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

In case of local variables with **automatic** storage duration, the Standard imposes **no** such requirement on the compilers. So the automatic variables are usually left uninitialized for performance reason — almost all major compilers choose this approach, though there might be a compiler which initializes the *automatic* variables also.

Comment: I still think it is a good idea to be explicit in both situations and it indicates to the reader of your code that you have thought about the initial value.

Comment: Imagine how many fewer bugs there would be in the world's C/C++ code if the default was to initialize all variables to zero. So as a local "int x;", x is guaranteed to be zero. If you really need the performance you could write something like "uninitialized int x;"

Comment: @joeking: When there are more than one choices, C and C++ has chosen (and is still choosing) the one which is more performant. Local : `int x[10000];` all elements of x is *uninitialized* by default (for performance reason); if you *really need* them to be zero-initialized, write : `int i[10000]={0};` now all elements are guaranteed to be zero. :-)

Comment: I'm just saying, we'd get more reliable software if the default was well-defined and you had to ask to get the unsafe but possibly more efficient behavior.
Obviously when "C" was being created it was a lot more important to worry about every last byte and cycle than it is today.

Comment: @joeking: What you're saying is not *only* "more reliable software". You're saying "more reliable **and less performant** software". So the answer is : C++ doesn't compromise with performance (and reliability can still be achieved by knowing the language better), which is why it doesn't initializes local variables, such as `pod_struct arr[10000];`. It would take **too much CPU cycles** to initialize this.

Answer (score 2):

*"A Four bytes memory slot is reserved for every defined integer."*.

No, it isn't. Disregarding the "4 bytes" size, the main problem with the statement is that modern compilers often find a new location for a variable each time it's assigned to. This can be a register or some place in memory. There's a lot of smartness involved.

An uninitialized variable isn't written to, so in general there's not even a place assigned for it. Trying to read "it" might not produce a value at all; the compiler can fail outright to generate code for that.

Now globals are another matter. Since they can be read and written from anywhere, the compiler can't just find new places for them on each write. They necessarily have to stick to one place, and it can't realistically be a register. Often they're all allocated together in one chunk of memory. Zeroing that chunk can typically be done very efficiently. that's why globals are different.

Answer (score 1):

As you might expect there are efficiency driven reasons behind this behavior as well.

Stack space is generally "allocated" simply by adjusting the stack pointer.
If you have 32 bytes of simple variables in a function then the compiler emits an instruction equivalent to "sp = sp - 32"
Any initialization of those variables would take additional code and execution time - hence they end up being initialized to apparently random values.

Global variables are another beast entirely.
Simple variables are effectively allocated by the program loader and can be located in what is commonly called "BSS". These variables take almost no space at all in the executable file. All of them can be merged together into a single block - so the executable image needs only specify the size of the block. Since the OS must ensure that a new process doesn't get to see any left-over data in memory from some now dead process, the memory needs to be filled with something - and you might as well fill it with zeros.

Global variables that are initialized to non-zeros actually do take up space in the executable file, they appear as a block of data and just get loaded into memory - there is no code in the executable to initialize these.

C++ also allows global variables that require code to be executed to initialize, C doesn't allow this.
For example "int x = rand();"
Get initialized at run time by code in the executable.

Try adding this global variable
   int x[1024 * 1024];
and see if it makes a difference to the executable size.
Now try:
   int x[1024 * 1024] = {1,2,3};
And see what difference that makes.

Comment: Actually, if you have 32 bytes of simple variables in a function, the compiler will reserve some number of bytes that's only tangentially related to 32. For instance, the return address often requires 4 extra bytes, registers need to be saved and temporaries may require stack space. On the other hand, not all users of stack space do so at the same time, and some objects may share the same stack space at different times.

Comment: Well sure, but for understanding the basics here you don't need to worry much about such details. 

Most compilers when generating debug mode code will give each local variable a unique slot on the stack (in addition to some small amount of overhead for other things) - allocated in a single block.